# IMO $2011$ problem $3$, how can I prove that $f(x) = 0, \; \forall \; x \leq 0 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a real-valued function defined on the set of real numbers that satisfies
$$f(x + y) \leq yf(x) + f(f(x))$$
for all real numbers $x$ and $y$. 
Prove that $f(x) = 0, \; \forall \; x \leq 0 .$

My attempts

I tried, $x=0, y=0, x=-y, y=-x$ and $x=y$, but I could not solve the problem.

$y=0$ then $f(x) \leq f(f(x))$

$x=0$ then $f(y) \leq yf(0)+f(f(0))$

$y=-x$, then $f(0)\leq -xf(x)+f(f(x))$

$x=-y$, then $f(0) \leq y(f(-y))+f(f(-y))$

$x=y$, then $f(2x) \leq xf(x)+f(f(x))$

Actually I tried more but I always failed. Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Just search for the problem on the site - More than 15 questions I've read about the same thing in the past quarter.

Comment: Look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h418798)

Comment: @rogerl I need a completely correct solution. There are several solutions. I dont know which of these are correct.